# Restore of database fails with '5(Access is denied)'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore database from another server, but I keep getting this error. I have tried changing security settings (giving permission) but still it keeps giving me this. Anybody have a clue how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Each SQL Server instance has its own (default) data folder. Is the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` folder actually owned by the instance you're trying to restore the backup to? Likely that's the folder path of the server from which the backup originates and you'll need to specify new file paths for the data and log files in your `RESTORE DATABASE` command. See: [Restoring a database and move files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#restoring_db_n_move_files) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user doesn't have permission to the location in which you are trying to restore the database. Please try to restore the database in another drive other than C or grant access to the user ,under which sql server is running, permission to the drive.

Just found another post with same problem. Please have a look:
[mssql '5 (Access is denied.)' error during restoring database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494407/mssql-5-access-is-denied-error-during-restoring-database)

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting SSMS in administrative mode and trying it again.